# Mocha give too long error message when testing node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I am learning node.js and how to test functions. I have a problem when using mocha: when functions are passing test, everything is completely fine, I get a nice looking message.

But if whichever function which doesnt pass a test - for example the result in the test is 0 but intentionally I wrote the asswertion to expect 1 - it gives me a mile long error massage in the bash-cli-console:

```js
Async functions
    (node:6001) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 0 == 1
        at utils.requestWikiPage.then.resBody (/home/sandor/Documents/learning-curve-master/node-dev-course/testing-tut/utils/utils.test.js:10:20)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    (node:6001) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:6001) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
        1) it should return a html page


      0 passing (2s)
      1 failing

      1) Async functions
           it should return a html page:
         Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/sandor/Documents/learning-curve-master/node-dev-course/testing-tut/utils/utils.test.js)
      



    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! dev-course@1.0.0 test: `mocha ./testing-tut/**/*.test.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the dev-course@1.0.0 test script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/sandor/.npm/_logs/2018-07-04T11_31_53_292Z-debug.log
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I dont know why do I get this part: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning...
and why do I get this part: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

the function I am testing: (it makes a request to wikipedia for the wiki page of george washington and collects the html page from the response. On 'end' of the responses readstream it resolves the html page. The function works just fine)

```js
// utils.js
function requestWikiPage() {
    const reqOpts = {
        hostname : 'en.wikipedia.org',
        port : 443,
        path : '/wiki/George_Washington',
        method : "GET"
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let req = https.request(reqOpts, (res) => {
            let resBody = "";
            res.setEncoding('utf-8');

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                resBody += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
              resolve(resBody);  
            });
        });

        req.on('err', (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

        req.end();
    });
}

module.exports.requestWikiPage = requestWikiPage;
```

Mocha code: (The 'resBody' variable is a string, containing a html page, where '' stays on the index of 0. In the assertion I test it for 1 to create an error message)

```js
const utils = require('./utils');
var assert = require('assert');

describe('Async functions', function() {
    it('it should return a html page', (done) => {
        utils.requestWikiPage().then(resBody => {
            assert.equal(resBody.indexOf('<!DOCTYPE html>'), 1);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

So I dont understand why do I get that long error message just because I expect to be  not on the 0 index than on the first? (Actually I get that error message whith every function not just with this)
How can I set up mocha that it gives me a more minimal and intuitive error message.
Thanks a million for your answers

Comment: set `this.timeout(10000)` inside your test case and try. By default it has `2000ms` timeout.

Comment: This is what you meant?:
describe('Async functions', function() {
    it('it should return a html page', (done) => {
        this.timeout(10000);
        utils.requestWikiPage().then(resBody => {
            assert.equal(resBody.indexOf('<!DOCTYPE html>'), 1);
            done();
        });
    });
});

Comment: yes you can do that....

Comment: Sorry still get the  same error meassage just with 'Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded...', but thanks for your Idea

Comment: Is your promise resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly reject the promise in `#requestWikiPage` if it doesn't resolve or there is an error, and then handle that rejection in your test. The following changes will likely solve the issue in your question (i.e. having mocha correctly handle a failed test without all the extra output), but the next step would obviously be getting your test to pass.

Notice we add the reject callback to our `new Promise()` and instead of `console.log(err);` below in your `req.on('error'...` callback, we now use `reject` as our error callback.

```js
// utils.js
function requestWikiPage() {
    const reqOpts = {
        hostname : 'en.wikipedia.org',
        port : 443,
        path : '/wiki/George_Washington',
        method : "GET"
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let req = https.request(reqOpts, (res) => {
            let resBody = "";
            res.setEncoding('utf-8');

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
              resBody += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
              resolve(resBody);  
            });
        });

        req.on('err', reject);

        req.end();
    });
}

module.exports.requestWikiPage = requestWikiPage;
```

And now handle if the promise is rejected via a catch block by using `done` as the catch callback (which would effectively pass the error to `done` which mocha requires).

```js
const utils = require('./utils');
var assert = require('assert');

describe('Async functions', function() {
    it('it should return a html page', (done) => {
        utils.requestWikiPage().then(resBody => {
            assert.equal(resBody.indexOf('<!DOCTYPE html>'), 1);
            done();
        }).catch(done);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lance, you have helped me really a lot.. I really appreciate it. Have a nice day